# Tags getting hidden in Stack Exchange android app feed when changing portrait to landscape mode and vice-versa

Tags: bug, tags, android-app, android-app-feed

In Stack Exchange android app **Feed** section when rotating the screen (from portrait to landscape and vice-versa) the tags are not visible for the post those have more than one tag.

**Steps to re-produce:**

1. Choose any post in the Feed, having more than one tag in Portrait mode.

   > [image: Portrait mode with more than one tag post]
2. Rotate into Landscape mode, now except the first tag the remaining tags are hide.

   > [image: Rotate to landscape mode first tag only visible]
3. Rotate back to Portrait mode, still the first tag only visible.

   > [image: Again come back to portrait mode still the first tag only visible]

The same issue is happening in the **Hot Questions** section also.

Stack Exchange Android App Version **1.0.77**

Comment: There is another rotation bug reported on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315305/578411

Comment: Repro'd on v1.0.82 (beta). To be exact, happened on any rotation, not only from portrait to landscape.